# Django : Can't auto insert user ID into other form

Tags: django, valueerror

I am trying to get user/customer info and copy it automatically to new model via custom form once requested but keep getting error. General overview as below.
(error : ValueError at /create_request/
Cannot assign "<SimpleLazyObject: <User: kambing>>": "OrderRequest.user" must be a "Customer" instance.)
[model relationship between customer model and request model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSAjI.jpg)

my views.py as below:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from accounts.models import *
from .forms import CreateRequestForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from accounts.models import *

@login_required(login_url='login')
def createRequest(request):
form = CreateRequestForm()
if request.method =='POST':
    form = CreateRequestForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        order = form.save(commit=False)
        order.user = request.user
        order.save()
    return redirect('/')

context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'commerce_autoparts/request_form.html', context)
```

here my model.py(autopart_ecommerce): Same as shown in attached image

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import Customer

class Logistic(models.Model):
logistic_method = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, 
 blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.logistic_method

class OrderRequest(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
null=True, blank=True)
ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True, blank=True)
link = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/images',null=True, 
blank=True)
price = models.FloatField(null=True)
draft = models.BooleanField(default=True)
logistic_method = models.ForeignKey(Logistic, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
note = models.TextField(max_length=100)
date_order = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I tried many solutions from stackoverflow but could not get it right. I am sorry if this not challenging question but I am stuck with this issue for some weeks. Some sort of guidance or reference available would be helpful.
I hope shared info is enough for your references.

Thank you

Comment: Can you add your model.py code?

Comment: I added the model.py details in the description for autoparts_commerce(same as image I attached).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it is a different model, so it doesn't like that. What you can do is copy the field data of the user to the customer, so you actually create new customer.

example:

```
# instead of this 
order.user = request.user
order.save()

# you could do
new_user = Customer()
new_user.name = request.user.name
new_user.email = request.user.email
new_user.last_name = request.user.last_name

# then pass the user to the order
order.user = new_user
order.save()
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I tried but it generate new error (WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name').

Answer (score 0):

I somehow manage to solve the issue. It was simply i don't refer the user to customer model. By adding the customer model (instance.user = request.user.customer), it automatically save the customer id once submitted. it may not be the perfect solution, but works for now..

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def createRequest(request):
form = CreateRequestForm(request.POST)
if request.method =='POST':
    form = CreateRequestForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user.customer
        instance.ref_code = get_ref_code()
        instance.save()
        return redirect('/')
```